# Excel - sorting

Tags: excel, sorting

Table 3 merges data from Table 1 and Table 2 based on index-match formula.

**Table 1:**

Name: Alex, Josh, Thomas

Quantity: 5, 10, 15

**Table 2:**

Name: Alex, Josh, Thomas

Fruit: apple, pear, orange

**Table 3:**

Name: Takes 1st, 2nd, 3row in Name, Table 1.

Quantity: Matches Quantity data from Table 1 to Name, Table 3

Fruit: Matches Fruit data from Table 2 to Name, Table 3

In Table 3 I would like to sort Largest to Smallest quantity. Because Name linked to row number in Table 1 and takes them consecutively, nothing happens. 
How do I sort the data without copy paste as values/ manual calculation of formulas?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Three formulas;

Start with the numbers in the second column of the third table.  Use Large to return the order of quantity desired:

```
=LARGE($B$2:$B$4,ROW(1:1))
```

Then for the Name we reference that column:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$4,MATCH(H2,$B$2:$B$4,0))
```

Then we reference the name for the fruit:

```
=INDEX($E$2:$E$4,MATCH(G2,$D$2:$D$4,0))
```

[image]